# USB 3.0 ethernet adapter not working — Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, 18.04, ethernet, adapter

I recently bought a new ethernet adapter for my laptop, but it always fails to connect to the internet. I have not touched my network settings (everything is set to automatic), I know the USB port works (and is 3.0), I've switched out the ethernet cable, and I've rebooted, and the problem remains. I looked at several similar questions and  didn't see an answer. Here are the outputs of a few relevant commands:

```
~$ ifconfig
enx00e04c680050: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::660a:4122:589c:5867  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:00:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13613  bytes 2126629 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 539  bytes 529852 (529.8 KB)
        TX errors 247  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3817  bytes 240361 (240.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3817  bytes 240361 (240.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.207  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::c550:81b5:cbfc:9922  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:d0:ab:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3473  bytes 4532992 (4.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2303  bytes 369202 (369.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The adapter interface is the first one, `enx00e04c6880050`.

```
~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The adapter is the Realtek device. Here's some of the output of `dmesg`; there was a lot more, but it was all exactly the same.

```
~$ dmesg | grep enx00e04c680050

[    3.145962] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: renamed from eth0
[    4.594647] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[    4.599211] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[    4.748235] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: carrier on
[    5.407467] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00e04c680050: link becomes ready
[  100.932975] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933018] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933057] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933095] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933135] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933183] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933342] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  100.933379] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Rx status -71
[  106.567052] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680050: renamed from eth0
[  106.598088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[  106.601933] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[  108.156517] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680050: carrier on
[  108.156551] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00e04c680050: link becomes ready
[  217.647356] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Stop submitting intr, status -71
[  306.017018] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: renamed from eth0
[  306.045732] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[  306.049858] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c680050: link is not ready
[  307.612495] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: carrier on
[  307.612522] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00e04c680050: link becomes ready
[  321.228465] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Tx status -71
[  321.231900] r8152 2-2:1.0 enx00e04c680050: Tx status -71
```

I also ran `dmesg` for the driver; these are the only two lines not already shown above:

```
~$ dmesg | grep r8152
[    2.833638] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    3.144927] r8152 1-2:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9
```

**EDIT**: I tried googling "Tx status -71," and I have the feeling that  [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1742922) — which seems to be an unresolved bug — is relevant, though I'm not entirely sure how to implement the provided patch, or if that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 2):

This [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) solved the same issue for me (with a Dell DA200 USB3 dock):

```
usbcore.quirks=0bda:8153:k
```

which disables Link Power Management for the device.
See also this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1713657) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/259#issuecomment-450585243) (for a different hardware with the same driver/NIC chip).

Comment: I have the same adapter and (probably) the same problem. (Although mine was working perfectly fine for some time.) What does this mean? Where do I change this and why? Why is that set of strings the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

This worked under Ubuntu 18.04.4. A service can be created under

> /etc/systemd/system/dell-quirks.service

with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Install quirks for DELL TypeC ethernet/VGA/ DA 200 adapter
Documentation=https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081128/usb-3-0-ethernet-adapter-not-working-ubuntu-18-04

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo 0bda:8153:k > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/quirks
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo 0bda:8153:k > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/quirks"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the daemon

> systemctl daemon-reload

Enable the service such that it starts on every reboot

> systemctl enable dell-quirks.service

Start the service

> systemctl start dell-quirks.service

Interface configuration has to be created. Before creating interface configuration ethernet interface can be given a name under

> /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

with following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*",ATTR{address}=="<MAC address of the ethernet interface>",ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",ATTR{type}=="1",KERNEL=="eth*",NAME="eth0"
```

After ethernet network configuration can be done with **netplan** by creating a yaml file

> /etc/netplan/01-network-card.yaml

with following content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

When the laptop is booting disconnect the USB device connect it after booting and it should work after couple of minutes. If required restart the **NetworkManager** and wait for couple of minutes.

> systemctl restart NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

make copies of the modified file

```
cp /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.backup
```

write:

```
lshw -c network
```

and save logical name ethernet card

go to file `nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and add in `ethernets:`

```
your-logical-name-ethernet:
  dhcp4: yes
```

the whole thing should look like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx00e04c480394:
      dhcp4: yes
```

save it and type

```
netplan --debug apply
```

in my case, renaming the card in /etc/udev/rules.d/ did not work and I had to enter the original name